# ModelState Validation

Tags: validation, rest, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api, modelstate

I just build a webapi using .Net. I have a Car Model in a post method and one of the field has Required property and an error message type. The problem is that when I don't enter anything in that specified field my message is not shown, I got only a message like an empty string ( "" ). Also, if I have a field of type int and I don't enter anything in that field the model state is not valid. How can I skip the conversion errors and how can I get the correct error message if I don't enter anything in required fields ? Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

My Model:

```
public class Car
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredName", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Car_Resources))]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredNumber", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Car_Resources))]
      public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[ValidateModelAttribute]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Car car)
{
}
```

ValidateModelAttribute method:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
     if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         var errors = new List<string>();
         foreach (var state in actionContext.ModelState)
         {
             foreach (var error in state.Value.Errors)
             {
                 errors.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
             }
         }

      actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors);
     }
}
```

Comment: When you say you got only a message like an empty string  -  what happens if you use `ErrorMessage` instead of  `ErrorMessageResourceName` - I'm wondering if it's working, but it's just not picking up your message from the resources (resx)?

Comment: No, It's not working. I think that it's because I don't set any value to Number for example. Also, the ModelState is trying to convert the field to their default value. For example Id is Guid but I receive a string as an Id and then, the ModelState will not be valid anymore because of the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. It's not the best one but if you use `[Required]` attribute on properties then you can use this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var errors = new List<string>();
        foreach (var state in actionContext.ModelState)
        {
            foreach (var error in state.Value.Errors)
            {
                if (error.Exception == null) 
                {
                    errors.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }

        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {
           actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors);
        }
    }
}
```

The properties which are required will not throw any exception, will have only the error message so you can filter on exception.